# iOS http post response to NSDictionary or NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, http, post, response

I'm making a HTTP Post and I would like to know how to convert the response to NSDictionary, or NSArray. Here's my code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SomeData=text", text];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.my.site/receiver"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

**EDIT:**

The response looks like this after converting like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

2011-12-04 11:50:00.924 Dancing Ruby[404:207] response: SID=DQAAAMAAAAAjy9MXrxh7Hi4nXTpyVTnqMR4c_W2wCQmLmO7xDHz7v91kl16tH-0UyazONU2nGjsUYxGzAPd9lvNcCGLfcz7YFLQRhG8yW8_wn3V46g8SY0A5bnfmGhuIbAMoCetow09cOnE7aYUzEZ4u5zVnJFoNepa9BlheFAA8JFLomw3luHedLkJZi_CQJO48CtwLZeIF9zhD5RNUDUretNh_1QBN2fHntSiqASMHHHyd9dtlTaXpokx_KIJovxo0dNYUJbs
LSID=DQAAAMIAAACgjuwUzSRNh2xXrWsdA81_fLVCguvatiHHU6b1dMm0TD6-lQyl-odfIfLGWgee4_j3HXUNsqtTm-aEFgylW2QURA5F9_1Fx8WRECIWOkUoLfWBGchoxRfhxKqCoD-zzgg1opjSmrDyv0U1NZRN7YGiqkLj4Fz_Qm6oPapov2_J33KT0ENFTKnqyzS0zU3wHgKSGb1aoKKO0ZJCTFk20AX3cLYPuMWoJcnyrLipCzZjkjwGEEhfgz31ISPS9OGezPzYJji-UxTmaJB7Va7SGquX
Auth=DQAAAMEAAACgjuwUzSRNh2xXrWsdA81_fLVCguvatiHHU6b1dMm0TD6-lQyl-odfIfLGWgee4_gex6ZHpCOn0tXFwuivD7ESwhFMJGdLRYSspk-leGqj-eCkXUgsg4DBvxPbdpREFlU_j0RGm_qufXlaScZV3x17plY5-xrhvhziEVFf3eLiHEmN9HHNwh8uElyYyJ1rLNAbIunpG3D10ASr4WPQDIz_52OOKy07CmQrBNDdUcpkT5bXqBe3Cdw8aqld0LZH2AIMEdj7PupfRaneJgF-nCBZ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some kind of parser for that. If the response is in XML you could use `NSXMLParser`. [Here](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) you can find a tutorial on how to use it. The same concept applies for any other kind of data. You have to know beforehand what to expect so you can parse it properly.

I hope it helps

Comment: I don't really know what is the format of the response, I edited the question

Comment: It doesn't seem to be any kind of standard format, just some key/value pairs. You will have to use `NSString` methods to get those, e.g you could use the `[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlineCharacterSet]` method to get every key/value pair.

Comment: well, this is what just happened.